# Security web inspector is not recognizing my frame busting as an effective one

Tags: javascript, security, iframe, fortify, clickjacking

I am running webinspect application to detect security threats on my application. One of the detected threats was (Cross-Frame Scripting) and I have fixed it by adding (X-Frame-Options) header to be (SAMEORIGIN). Now, when I re-run the webinspect it still detects (Cross-Frame Scripting) and the following message is reported with it:

> An effective frame-busting technique was not observed while loading
>   this page inside a frame

I have used a lot of block busting code but the same problem persists.
I have tried the following block killers:

First try:

```
 <style> html{display:none;} </style> 
   <script>    
    if(self == top) {
    document.documentElement.style.display = 'block';} 
    else {
    top.location = self.location; } 
</script>
```

Second try:

```
if (top != self) { top.location.replace(self.location.href); }
```

Third try:

```
if(top.location!=self.locaton) {
  parent.location = self.location;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define an "effective one".

While the three JavaScript snippets you did present do work, have you looked at ways to stop that?

For example, in the iframe (which the attacker would control), add the sandbox attribute with an empty value:

```
<iframe src="Inner.html" sandbox="">
```

*[iframe documentation](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/iframe)*

Here is a sample test I did:

**Outer.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Outer Html</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Outer Html</h1>
        <p>
            Outer Html
        </p>
        <iframe src="Inner.html" width="400" height="300" sandbox="">
            <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Inner.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Inner Html</title>
   <script>    
    if (top != self) { top.location.replace(self.location.href); }
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Inner Html</h1>
        <p>
            Inner Html
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**X-Frame-Options**

If you are using the `X-Frame-Options` and the JavaScript code to make sure you are not in a frame, why not set the value to `DENY` instead of `SAMEORIGIN`?

With `SAMEORIGIN` your attack surface is smaller, it will only be successful the iframe is coming from your site (possible with another vulnerability).  If you are not going to be doing iframes on your site, you might as well go with the safer option of `X-Frame-Options: DENY`.

I think this is what HPE Fortify WebInspect is expected.

**Content Security Policy (CSP) frame-ancestors directive**

Another option is to use the `frame-ancestors` directive with the 'none' value in the HTTP Header 'Content-Security-Policy'.  This will prevent (in supported browsers) any domain from framing the content.  This setting is recommended unless a specific need has been identified for framing.

**Great Resource**

You can find more information about prevetion of Clickjacking over at the [OWASP's Clickjacking Defense Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try

Comment: @Rotem no it did not

Comment: @Ala So did you find another way to pass Fortify by demand's scan?

Comment: @Rotem unfortunately I did not find another way :(

Comment: I used the solution presented on the OWSAP wiki and it worked just fine.. @Ala

Comment: @Rotem can you please presented here?

Comment: There is no "NONE" value for X-Frame-Options. You should use "DENY" if you want to completely disable framing

Comment: @CagatayKalan Wow, I don't know how I screwed that up.  Thanks for bring that to my attention.  I have also added in CSP protection and the OWASP cheat sheet.